# How to divide numbers from different tables in pig

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig

I am trying to join two tables and divide a number from one table by a number from another table. I have attempted to do it in the original and generate a new table with the same values but I get the same error both times which is extra confusing to me.

```
--get the data 
lines = LOAD '/historicaldata.csv' USING PigStorage(' ') AS (ticker:chararray, date:long, open:long, high:long, low:long, close:long, volume:long);

--limit it between the dates we want
specDates = FILTER lines BY (date<=20000103 and date>=19900101);

--sort by ticker symbol
companies = GROUP specDates BY ticker;

--sort DESC and get the top to get the ending date
sorted_end = FOREACH companies {
    sorted1 = ORDER specDates BY date DESC;
    endDate = LIMIT sorted1 1;
    GENERATE endDate.ticker AS ticker, endDate.open AS open, endDate.close AS close;
}

--sort ASC and get the top to get the starting date
sorted_begin = FOREACH companies {
    sorted2 = ORDER specDates BY date ASC;
    startDate = LIMIT sorted2 1;
    GENERATE startDate.ticker AS ticker, startDate.open AS open, startDate.close AS close;
}

joined = JOIN sorted_end BY ticker, sorted_begin BY ticker;
final = FOREACH joined GENERATE sorted_end::ticker as ticker, sorted_begin::open as open, sorted_end::close as close;
final2 = FOREACH final GENERATE ticker as ticker, (float)(close/open) as growth_factor;
```

The error I keep getting is:

```
(Name: Divide Type: null Uid: null)incompatible types in Divide Operator left hand side:bag :tuple(close:float)  right hand side:bag :tuple(open:float)
```

Both are floats so I am not sure why they are "incompatible types" other than that they come from different bags, but adding them to "final" and trying to do it from there doesn't work.

The data is in the form:

```
AA,20140131,11.60,11.80,11.45,11.48,33014100
AA,20140130,12.05,12.07,11.83,11.92,23223500
AA,20140129,11.64,12.23,11.58,11.96,44433000
```

Every entry includes all columns and are well formatted, non-zero numbers

Comment: post your complete code and some sample inputs

Comment: Post sample data from both the datasets that you are joining along with schema for them.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your query, I tried to create a dummy table on my system and generate the result. I found no issue and the division operation was completed successfully. PFB some sample queries which I fired on Pig:-

```
A = LOAD '/home/training/716391/pig/pigdata.csv' USING PigStorage(',') as (ID:INT, name:CHARARRAY, GPC:FLOAT)
B = LOAD '/home/training/716391/pig/pigdata2.csv' USING PigStorage(',') as (ID:INT, name:CHARARRAY, GPC:FLOAT)
C = join A by ID, B by ID
D = FOREACH C generate A::ID as IDA, A::name as NAMEA, A::GPC as GPCA, B::ID as IDB, B::name as NAMEB, B::GPC as GPCB;
E = FOREACH D GENERATE IDA, (FLOAT)(GPCA/GPCB) AS VALUE;
```

Can you please confirm, if the divisor value in your case has no Null value or 0?

Could you please share the load statements for sorted_end and sorted_begin?

Comment: Yeah, I'll post the full code, maybe something I did earlier on is causing this trouble. All the divisors should be non null, non zero values

Comment: I cannot see much issue with the query except that 'ticker' values in sorted_end and sorted_being would be different and hence the join relation 'joined' generating an empty relation. This is because you are grouping it by ticker (companies relation) but later sorting it by date (asc and desc) and selecting just one tupple from each relation. This could have resulted in different 'ticker' value at each relation.